# positioning items in android dev

Tags: android, user-interface, coordinates

Hi
I'm totaly new to android,
I'm looking for a very very very simple thing that in every possible dev env is straight forward, except apparently android.
how the hell do I set X and Y for every UI object that I wanna place there.
For example in xml i have LinearView or RelativeView and in them I have Button, I'm looking for a way to set this button position on the screen using Y and Y, should be pretty straight forward thingy, I mean in iOS dev you just do CGRectMake(x,y,width,height) and there you go.
What is the equivalent in android dev?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> Android is designed to run on a
>   variety of devices that offer a range
>   of screen sizes and resolutions

So, unless you are targeting only one specific Android device, you'd not want to use absolute coordinates, as, for exemple, x=300px on one device can mean a reference outside the screen on another device(a small-screen one).
Instead, you learn to use just relative positions as top, bottom, below, etc, that works on every device.

Try to do the Hello Views [tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) first, in order to better understand how things are working for Android.

Comment: you are right, for example if I want to put an edit field and underneath this edit field i need to put 2 buttons it's easy, but how do I arrange all of these items with the appropriate distances from each other?

Comment: How do you know the appropriate distance that works on every device?! Though, you can set some ratio using LiniarLayout, or use properties like `android:padding` and `android:layout-margin`, and others like that to arrange the items on the screen.

Comment: thanks for the help, I think I'm starting to get the gist of it, the main iOs advantage is that it has only 1 screen size! so it is easy not to deal with all the porting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please use layout_x and layout_y with a AbsoluteLayout in your layout xml.