# Dynamic positioning of a Button [Android]

Tags: android, button, android-layout, position, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout which holds an ImageView and an ImageButton. The ImageView serves as an container for a background image. Now I'm trying to set the button at a fixed position so that it always appears on the same position on the background image.

Here is the layout file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/bg_1" android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<ImageButton android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_1" android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgButton" android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I've tried positioning the button with it's left-/top-margin using dp as unit, but this doesn't work. Since the background image is beeing scaled down/up, the position would have to be dynamic in some kind of way.

I understand that absolute positioning, with pixel-values for x-/y-position, is something that won't work on Android, like it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299551/positioning-items-in-android-dev). I still need to solve this and am not sure how.

Would I have to calculate the values for left-/top-margin (not sure how that would be) and then set them with something like this?

```
final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int width = (int)((float)120 * density); 
int height = (int)((float)120 * density); 

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
rlp.leftMargin = newMargin;
rlp.topMargin = newTopMargin;

ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
imgButton.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

Hope I didn't forget something ...

//EDIT:
I was thinking, the reason for the issue might be, that the scaled image has different "borders", depending on the screen size. 
With an image at a 1:1.6 ratio on a HVGA screen I have black bars on the left and right, whereas on a WVGA screen the bars are on the left. Considering I'm using the default scaling. I will look into it and post again, if necessaray...

Answer (score 0):

Why scaling happens? Because of different dpi on different devices? Do you have different drawabled for different dpi settings? If it isn't just dpi issue and you want to scale that background image freely then you can't do the job using standard layouts. You should implement a custom one.

Comment: If you mean the scaling of the background image. Yes it is because of the different screen resolutions and densitys. I actually don't know how I would have to customize a view to solve this problem.

Comment: Oh btw. I do have my background image in different sizes, but I was thinking that would just effect the visual representation, since it reduces the amount of scaling that is applied on the image.

Comment: You should write a custom layout then. There is a nice example in: http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html

Minute 44